# Python: JSON to Dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

Two examples for a JSON request. Both examples should have the correct JSON syntax, yet only the second version seems to be translatable to a dictionary.

```
#doesn't work
string_js3 = """{"employees": [
{
    "FNAME":"FTestA",
    "LNAME":"LTestA",
    "SSN":6668844441
},
{
    "FNAME":"FTestB",
    "LNAME":"LTestB",
    "SSN":6668844442
}
]}
"""

#works
string_js4 = """[
{
    "FNAME":"FTestA",
    "LNAME":"LTestA",
    "SSN":6668844441
},
{
    "FNAME":"FTestB",
    "LNAME":"LTestB",
    "SSN":6668844442
}]
"""
```

This gives an error, while the same with string_js4 works

```
L1 = json.loads(string_js3)
print(L1[0]['FNAME'])
```

So I have 2 questions:
1) Why doesn't the first version work
2) Is there a simple way to make the first version also work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these strings are valid JSON.  Where you are getting stuck is in how you are accessing the resulting data structures.

- `L1` (from `string_js3`) is a (nested) `dict`;
- `L2` (from `string_js4`) is a `list` of `dicts`.

Walkthrough:

```
import json

string_js3 = """{
    "employees": [{
            "FNAME": "FTestA",
            "LNAME": "LTestA",
            "SSN": 6668844441
        },
        {
            "FNAME": "FTestB",
            "LNAME": "LTestB",
            "SSN": 6668844442
        }
    ]
}"""

string_js4 = """[{
        "FNAME": "FTestA",
        "LNAME": "LTestA",
        "SSN": 6668844441
    },
    {
        "FNAME": "FTestB",
        "LNAME": "LTestB",
        "SSN": 6668844442
    }
]"""


L1 = json.loads(string_js3)
L2 = json.loads(string_js4)
```

The resulting objects:

```
L1
{'employees': [{'FNAME': 'FTestA', 'LNAME': 'LTestA', 'SSN': 6668844441},
  {'FNAME': 'FTestB', 'LNAME': 'LTestB', 'SSN': 6668844442}]}

L2
[{'FNAME': 'FTestA', 'LNAME': 'LTestA', 'SSN': 6668844441},
 {'FNAME': 'FTestB', 'LNAME': 'LTestB', 'SSN': 6668844442}]

type(L1), type(L2)
(dict, list)
```

> 1) Why doesn't the first version work?

Because calling `L1[0]` is trying to return the value from the key `0`, and that key doesn't exist.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), "It is an error to extract a value using a non-existent key."  `L1` is a dictionary with just one key:

```
L1.keys()
dict_keys(['employees'])
```

> 2) Is there a simple way to make the first version also work?

There are several ways, but it ultimately depends on what your larger problem looks like.  I'm going to assume you want to modify the Python code rather than the JSON files/strings themselves.  You could do:

```
L3 = L1['employees'].copy()
```

You now have a list of dictionaries that resembles `L2`:

```
L3
[{'FNAME': 'FTestA', 'LNAME': 'LTestA', 'SSN': 6668844441},
 {'FNAME': 'FTestB', 'LNAME': 'LTestB', 'SSN': 6668844442}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and clarification :)